# Sine squared function solving for the variable a degrees

Tags: trigonometry

Find degree a:

$$\sin^{2}(a-20)-\sin^{2}(a+20) = 0.1714$$

Everything is in degrees.

How do I solve this for a?

Comment: I used the traditional slow way and got sin(a)cos(a)=-0.1333. Now how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a nice **identity**: $$\sin^2(x)-\sin^2(y)=\sin(x+y)\, \sin(x-y)$$

So, $$\sin(2a)\sin(-40)=0.1714$$ from there you can find $2a$ by a calculator.

Comment: wow i've never seen this before this is so random

Answer (score 0):

...or you can use the conjugate rule:

$$\sin^{2}(a-20)-\sin^{2}(a+20)=(\sin(a-20)+\sin(a+20))(\sin(a-20)-\sin(a+20))=
-2\sin a\cos20\cdot 2\cos a\sin20=-2\sin20\cos20\sin(2a)=-\sin(40)\sin(2a)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: make use of the identities:

$$\sin{\alpha \pm \beta} = \sin{\alpha} \cos{\beta} \pm \cos{\alpha} \sin{\beta},$$ with $\alpha = a$ and $\beta = 20º$. When you substitute this back in your equation, the $\sin^2 \cos^2$ operators will vanish so you will end up for a single equation for $\sin{a}\cos{a} = \pm \sin{a} \, \sqrt{1-\sin^2{a}}$.

Hope this helps.

Edit: a much more nicer answer is provided by the user @mesel.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but actually my name is mesel :)

Comment: Fixed now. Sorry!

Comment: I just make a joke no need for sorry.